# What could be the equivalent term in British or Australian English to the American English word “hillbilly”?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, slang, australian-english

In Wikipedia, “hillbilly” is defined as:
… a term referring to certain people who dwell in rural, mountainous areas of the United States, primarily Appalachia but also the Ozarks. Owing to its strongly stereotypical connotations, the term is frequently considered derogatory, and so is usually offensive to those Americans of Appalachian heritage.

I am looking for a term of equivalent meaning  denoting the highly loaded emotional characteristic.

Comment: Here's an attempt at the answer: http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2008/09/the-british-equivalent-of-redneck.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In British English there is the word *yokel* which has much the same pejorative overtones.

> **yokel** *noun*
>   an uneducated and unsophisticated person from the countryside.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yokel)

Answer (score 14):

While I'd agree that Andrew Leach's answer *yokel* is a good word for this, perhaps you could also (for British English) consider *[bumpkin](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bumpkin)*:-

> An awkward, unsophisticated person; a yokel.

Answer (score 11):

Likewise, in (colloquial) Australian English, [*bogan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogan) can be considered roughly equivalent:

> The term **bogan** (/ˈboʊɡən/) is Australian and New Zealand slang, usually pejorative or self-deprecating, for an individual who is recognised to be from an unsophisticated background or someone whose speech, clothing, attitude and behaviour exemplifies a lack of manners and education. <sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>

Comment: I tend to think of bogans as more suburban than hillbillies, but still a good fit.

Comment: When I lived in Australia we sometimes referred to them as *bushbillies*.

Answer (score 10):

The previously-mentioned terms *[bumpkin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bumpkin#Noun)*  (“a yokel;
a clumsy, unsophisticated person)” and  *[yokel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yokel#Noun)* (“(pejorative) An unsophisticated person”, also “A person of rural background”) both appear in the  [British-equivalent-of-redneck](http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2008/09/the-british-equivalent-of-redneck.html) virtuallinguist link given in a third answer.  The linked page also states that   “The words hick and hillbilly are used too (also pejoratively) but not very often”, and it goes on to mention slightly-less-relevant terms  *[chav](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chav#Noun)* (“(UK, pejorative, offensive) A working-class youth, especially one associated with aggression, poor education, and a perceived "common" taste in clothing and lifestyle”) and  *[pikey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pikey#Noun_2)* (“(UK, pejorative) A working-class (often underclass) person; can vary from specifically Irish Travellers to gypsies or travellers from any ethnic background, but now increasingly used for any socially undesirable person, with negative connotations...”), besides some dialectical or little-used but perhaps well-known terms like Scottish *heuchter-teuchter* and Irish  *[culchie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culchie#Noun)* (“(Dublin, slang, pejorative, offensive) A rural person”) and some more-general terms like *[provincial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provincial#Noun)* and *[parochial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parochial#Adjective)*.

However, the previous answers and the virtuallinguist link fail to mention the noun *[rustic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rustic#Noun)*, which means “A (sometimes unsophisticated) person from a rural area”.  Wiktionary illustrates it via the following quote from  Arthur Conan Doyle's story *Sir Nigel*:

> The King looked at the motionless figure, at the little crowd of hushed expectant rustics beyond the bridge, and finally at the face of Chandos, which shone with amusement.

Comment: But (at least in the US) "rustic" could be positive, much more than "hillbilly".

Comment: So can *hillbilly*. It is a matter of context and intent.

Comment: *Rustic charm* is well-appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Aussies use the terms "redneck" and "yokel".
We also can be more geographically specific, and typically inventive. 
A resident of the rural township of Nerang (Qld) is called a "Nerangutang".

Answer (score 2):

Although not strictly what you asked for, I thought I'd add some **Irish** equivalents.
The main ones are:

[Culchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culchie) - derived from the name of the village Kiltimagh

or

Bogger - because much of rural Ireland is covered in [bog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog)(especially those that are traditionally the poorest).

Other words words like hick, bumpkin, red-neck or yokel are used or would be understood.

Answer (score 1):

I like 'Pictish' used as an adjective, referring to the Picts, barbaric tribes of Scotland during the Roman occupation. But not even the English will have any notion of what you're talking about. I've heard it used by Rupert Everett in the movie 'An Ideal Husband'.

Answer (score 1):

One term that shouldn't be overlooked in the context of this question is [*peasant:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/peasant)

> 1 A poor farmer of low social status who owns or rents a small piece of land for cultivation (chiefly in historical use or with reference to subsistence farming in poorer countries).
>
> 1.1 *informal* **An ignorant, rude, or unsophisticated person; a person of low social status.**

(Definitions from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "Boor" fits as an answer to this question the question reasonably.  It has the churlish/crass connotation without being excessively stereotypical. It is also more typically used in Britain/Australia than in the US.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/boor

Comment: *Boor* is well-understood in the U.S., but there is no association with backwoods areas here—there are plenty of people in big cities and university towns acting boorishly who are described as such.

Comment: Oh, right.  I thought the original question was an answer.  I wasn't focusing on the need to come from the rural countryside.  I would vote for "bumpkin" then. https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/150422-Any-British-term-for-hick